# Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) memory exceeded continuously

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I uploaded my react project on Heroku but it shows this error message and memory exceeded continuously I did not get any answer or any reference from available questions on StackOverflow that's why I asking my own question. After the javascript heap size issue, I have extended the value of max old space. I am using `react-script instead` of `webpack-dev-server`.

`--max_old_space_size=4096` 
How can I solve this ??

Comment: Check if this helps:  https://serverfault.com/a/715035

Comment: @Jai Thank you for the reference but how can I use this `web: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=920 --gc_interval=100 server.js` `--max_old_space_size=920` set in Node_options so `--gc_interval` and `--optimize_for_size` where I can set??